# Pulling the last new child added

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Having a bit of an issue with syntax errors that I can't seem to figure out.

If I wanted to pull the last child object each time A child is added how would I do that? Right now I tried:

```
Firebase().database().ref('stuff').limit(1).on('child_added', function(snapshot) { ...
```

But getting undefined is not a function. I tried this as well, but didn't seem to work.

```
Firebase().database().ref('stuff').endAt().limit(1).on('child_added', function(snapshot) { ...
```

Is this type of functionality possible? Or am I going about this the wrong way? Thanks!

Comment: What is `Firebase()`? Typically, it would be `firebase.database()...`

Comment: You're probably looking for `firebase.database()` with a lowercase `F` and without parenthesis.

Comment: Nah, I know its not that.. thats just the way I have it setup in my code.. the firebae.databae ().ref () part is not the issue.. its what comes after

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should grab the reference and then get its child:

```
firebase.database().ref().child('stuff').limit(1).on('child_added', function(snapshot) { ...
```